# Fix for Cross-Origin Read Blocking (CORB) blocked cross-origin response warning

Tags: cross-origin-read-blocking

I have been having this issue starting today , This wasn't an issue until last evening , I was able to hit the API and get the web-app working , The app is built using React-JS,Initially at the very beginning we had the CORS Issue and the CORS plugin was installed and enabled to have it working . Now the issue with CORB has cropped up , Went through the fixes none of them worked. All our APIs are invoked in this manner :

```
fetch('API_URL', {
    headers: {
      'Accept': 'application/json, text/plain, application/xml,  */*',
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': 'Content-Type',
    },
    method: 'POST',
    body: JSON.stringify(req)
  })
```

Comment: Hi Folks , Any inputs regarding this ? It's been almost a day and I have been having this issue , I am not able to proceed further

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has been resolved , I just ran this : chrome.exe --disable-web-security , this is on windows , The CORB issue is resolved.

Comment: Client sided fixes are not a solution. This has to do with incorrect content headers.